# Is there a function like Processing's map() (where I take a value and 'resize' it to a range?)

Tags: vba, excel

In Processing, there's a "map()" function that works like this:

```
float someValue = 25
float m = map(someValue, 0, 100, 0, 500);
```

which re-maps a number from one range to another.

In the example above, the number 25 is converted from a value in the range of 0 to 100 into a value that ranges from 0 to 500.

It's a quicker way of 'resizing' a number instead of doing the math that would do so.

Is there some kind of function like this in VBA?

Basically, I am trying to do something like (psuedo code):

```
for i = 0 to 20
    Shapes.addline(10,10,20,i).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,i)
Next
```

But I want that "i" to scale from 0 to 255, so the line at (10,10)(20,2) has not RGB (0,0,2) but something like (0,0,34) or whatever would be the scale...

Does that make sense? Thanks for any ideas/help/advice!

Comment: why don't you divide i to `12.75` as `RGB` -use `int()` for integer result- ;). `12.75 = 255 / 20`

Comment: @shA.t - yeah, I think I'll just do that.  I'll look in to making a function using that idea to create a MAP() within Excel. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need my answer I'm going to delete it :(.

Answer (score 0):

There is this function called the [Rnd](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php) in VBA, which can give you a Random Number between a range. So you could do something like,

```
Dim rgbInd As Integer

For i = 0 To 20
    rgbInd = Int ((255 - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
    Shapes.addline(10, 10, 20, i).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, rgbInd)
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim c as integer, m as integer, n as integer
m = 255 'or any number that you want.
n = 20  'or num of variant color you specified
For i = 0 to m
    c = Int(i * n / m)
    Shapes.addline(10,10,20,i).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,c)
Next
```

;)

Comment: Did you try executing this code? I did and I got this as result `0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 `. Should the formula for **c** not be `c = Int(i * m / m)`, which might give the result `0  12  25  38  51  63  76  89  102  114  127  140  153  165  178  191  204  216  229  242  255 `

Comment: `m / m = 1` ---- as `int (n /m)` you will have repeated values, when you set varity of colors (n) is 20 for 255 line (m) so you will 13 repeat of each color from [1-13] as (n/m = 12.75 => Int(n/m) = 13).

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be `c = Int(i * m / n)`, n/m would give `7.84313725490196E-02`, so explains the `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `, where if it is `m/n` it would be `12.75`

Comment: i = 0 only once, if the OP does not want to use 0, he/she can use i+1. **HOWEVER**, that will mean the range is out of the window `12  25  38  51  63  76  89  102  114  127  140  153  165  178  191  204  216  229  242  255  267 `, **267 > 255**

Comment: **RGB** function range. Each argument will take a value between **0-255**. Well the function changes anything greater than 255 will be converted to 255. So it should be fine I guess.

Comment: Can you give me an example for `i` and `c`, plz. .... `i = 255 => c = int( _255_ * 20 / _255_) = 20`

Comment: This is my last comment :As I said in comment of question `i` should divide to `12.75 = 255 / 20` => so do it `i / (m / n)` and if remember in math it is equal to `i * n / m`. plz no more comment .